# Does the trace and determinant uniquely determine the eigenvalues of a 3 by 3 matrix with algebraic multiplicity of 2?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, vector-analysis, trace

I have a 3 by 3 matrix $M$ whose eigenvalues are $a$, $b$, and $b$.

The determinant and trace of $M$ are known from its eigenvalues: $det(M)=ab^2$ and $Tr(M)=2b+a$.

I wanted to show that if $Tr(M)=3 \ \sqrt[3]{det(M)}$, then $a=b$. I was told that this one equation is not sufficient to completely determine $M$'s eigenvalues to all be equal, if it is already know that it has at least algebraic multiplicity of 2.

Does the trace and determinant uniquely determine the eigenvalues of a 3 by 3 matrix with algebraic multiplicity of 2?

## General Case

[image]

Comment: How does a $3 \times 3$ matrix have "*at least two degenerate eigenvalues*"? To be degenerate, they must have multiplicity greater than one. Having at least two degenerate eigenvalues means, counted with multiplicity, there are at least four eigenvalues. A $3 \times 3$ matrix can have, counted with multiplicity, *at most* three eigenvalues. The eigenvalues are solutions of the (cubic) characteristic equation.

Comment: Sorry, I used the word triple degenerate and double degenerate. I am not sure what the appropriate wording should be.

Comment: you want to use the word (algebraic) multiplicity, so some eigenvalue has multiplicity at least 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two variables and two equations, $d=ab^2$ and $t=a+2b$ where $d,t$ are some constants.  Solve this system of equations:

$a=t-2b \rightarrow d=(t-2b)b^2 \rightarrow 2b^3-tb^2+d=0$

So you have a cubic in $b$ which has a generic solution with 3 roots $b_1,b_2,b_3$.  Each of these determines a corresponding value for $a$, so in general your determinant and trace only determine the eigenvalues up to choosing a solution $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3)$

Comment: Wow. I did not even consider the 3 possible roots. More specifically, my $M$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Comment: Should I post a variation of this question, more specific to a positive definite symmetric matrix?

Comment: In that case (positive definite symmetric), all the eigenvalues need to be real and positive.  You can still have multiple real and positive solutions to the system of equations above: for example when $t=4,d=1$ the cubic has two positive real solutions $b_1,b_2$ both yielding a positive real solution for $a$, call them $a_1,a_2$.  You can check that $a_1 \neq b_1$,$a_2 \neq b_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\text{tr}(M)=-6$ and $\det(M)=-8$, then you could have eigenvalues $1,1,-8$ or $-2, -2, -2$

Comment: Wow. I did not even consider the 3 possible roots. More specifically, my $M$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.